# Transaction working fine for Sandbox Account, Not for Live Account using Master Card

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When integrated authorized.net using SIM,and for merchant authentication using Login ID and Transaction Key, I was able to do all transaction using Master Card using the sandbox account.

But when I tried with the live account, the transaction using Master Card is not working. What could be the issue?

I am using following card:

`370000000000002 (American Express)`

`6011000000000012 (Discover)`

`5424000000000015 (Master Card)`

`4007000000027 (Visa)`

The issue exists for both iPhone and android app.

Comment: I got the issue fixed,as I came to know that there exist two type of transaction one "authonly" and other "authcapture".When you do "authonly" the merchant need to manually settle his or her transaction,while auth capture automatically settles the transaction as soon as it is done.Mine was the auth_only,so overtime i made a transaction i had to settle it from my authorized .net account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the issue fixed,as I came to know that there exist two type of transaction one "authonly" and other "authcapture".When you do "authonly" the merchant need to manually settle his or her transaction,while auth capture automatically settles the transaction as soon as it is done.Mine was the auth_only,so overtime i made a transaction i had to settle it from my authorized .net account.